# Why are TrueCrypt/VeraCrypt write speeds so *disproportionately* slow?

Tags: ssd, performance, encryption, truecrypt, veracrypt

When I try to use TrueCrypt or VeraCrypt, write speeds are very slow, but read speeds are fast. This happens with both programs, and it occurs **regardless** of whether I'm using an encrypted file container or an encrypted partition. (So, no, this isn't fragmentation etc.)

For example, on my SSD where unencrypted read and write speed **both** benchmark **over 1GB/s** on CrystalDiskMark, an encrypted volume using AES-XTS and HMAC-RIPEMD-160 benchmarks read speeds of **810 MB/s** vs. write speeds of **40 MB/s**.

Why are encrypted writes so much slower than encrypted reads?

(And no, I'm not doing something silly like benchmarking in a VM. I swear I've already thought of all the "easy" answers and they don't explain the situation as far as I can tell.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is a VeraCrypt partition slower?](https://superuser.com/questions/988823/is-a-veracrypt-partition-slower)

Comment: "Why are encrypted writes so much slower than encrypted reads?" The unencrypted write time should be significantly longer than the read time, so that benchmark is suspect.  But the encryption process takes longer than the decryption process.  It isn't clear what level of detail you're looking for to explain the difference.

Comment: @fixer1234: *"The unencrypted write time should be significantly longer than the read time, so that benchmark is suspect."* ...no, my benchmark isn't suspect; you just haven't seen fast SSDs. However, I'm not aware of encryption taking 20x more time than decryption; it should be about the same as far as I'm aware. If you believe otherwise, you don't really need any detail to prove it: just show me a program (or use standard OpenSSL commands) that demonstrate encryption taking 20x longer than decryption. I'll happily accept such an answer.

Comment: @Keltari: No, this isn't a duplicate of that... my read speed is so ridiculously faster than my write speed, even for the encrypted partition. That guy was just wondering why encryption was slower than plaintext... it doesn't explain the read-write discrepancy.

Comment: What model CPU do you have?

Comment: @davidgo: I don't see how the model could possibly explain the read vs. write difference, but 7820HQ...

Comment: It won't be the issue in your build -  but I was wondering if the CPU was lacking AeS-NI support.

Comment: @davidgo: Yeah I got that part, but how would that make the read so much faster than the write?

Comment: That's amusingly slow compared to cryptsetup on a variety of cheap hardware https://forum.odroid.com/viewtopic.php?f=149&t=30103&p=215037

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure it's the encryption alone causing the speed differences?

First, your drive could be using compression to return artificially high unencrypted read & write speeds. [This article](https://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/ssd-file-system-ntfs,3166-3.html) (also linked below) shows *"Zalman actually draws an honest picture of data compression and its effect. The chart on its product website clearly shows that writing incompressible data may happen slower that compressible information."* with [the graphic](https://img.purch.com/w/730/aHR0cDovL21lZGlhLmJlc3RvZm1pY3JvLmNvbS8xL1QvMzMxODQxL29yaWdpbmFsL1phbG1hbl9jb21wcmVzc2libGVfU1NELmpwZw==) showing incompressible reads 500MB/s and incompressible writes ~160MB/s.

And if the drive was full or wasn't TRIMed it could slow down writes from needing to erase sectors before writing. It's a security leak to even use TRIM with encryption, since it reveals which sectors are empty, and VeraCrypt may not be TRIMing (it really shouldn't), slowing writes.

And  CrystalDiskMark (or the SSD itself) could be strongly influenced by the filesystem and type of test being done. I'd try several different tests, and different benchmarks too (like AS SSD & Iometer & PCMark) and real-world usage tests before concluding that slow encryption is the only possible cause.

This article on Tom's Hardware, [Does Your SSD's File System Affect Performance?](https://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/ssd-file-system-ntfs,3166.html), shows wildly different read & write speeds for three different filesystems on two different SSD's, without any encryption. Here's a few of the results:

[image]

Reads could even be much slower[image: description]

[image]

[image]

Comment: As if I needed more reasons to hate FAT32...

Comment: Old question and answer, but still... Indeed y default Veracrypt disables TRIM on non-system partitions, and this *might* explain slower writes to some extent. https://www.veracrypt.fr/en/Trim%20Operation.html

Answer (score -3):

Short answer will be - change your ssd model for veracrypt.

Oh, that's long :) Drive, that has writing speeds exceeding 300MB/s had only  around 30MB/s writing when was encrypted by veracrypt...

I'll create question from that if I won't find solution or couse :)

Long answer - I've had the same issue when I was benchmarking few weeks my disks from simple boredom, I think, that I've found really strange bug in veracrypt or Ssd itself... I had 3 spare ssds (two 1tb,one 2tb) from two brands, and three new cheap Chinese usb cases. I was just curious if current usb case (which od two were transparent, and I knew that were slightly different) can affect drive performance and if cheapest usb is enough to use full potential of sata3 drive nowadays. I've tried samsung 850 pro 1tb, samsung 870 2tb, and some kind of server or pro series intel 960Gb. I've tried every disk with every enclosure with atto disk benchmark (even with file length of 32Gb). And results of my test were really consistent - in all cases, all disk were very close to each other (difference of few mb/s depending on which usb case. Both read and write speed in standard conditions. Later I thought that I'll check how much veracrypt affects performance nowadays. It really doesn't affect almost nothing on my old i7-6700K cpu. But one drive had strange issue - that Samsung 1TB 850 PRO couldn't archive more write then 20-30mb/s,just like yours. I've tried everything - changing filesystem from fat, by exfat to NTFS, tried different allocation units, encryption algorithms, simply everything. Also I've fully trimed in Windows, and becouse of easiness and not believing in Microsoft tools, I've even trimmed it manually, by Linux bash loop each 64k sectors by 64k sectors by `hdparm --trim-sector-range` command xD I don't remember exact numers, but easily every disk achieved read and writing at 300mb/s+ in every atto test, but strangely that samsung couldn't write anything faster when drive was encrypted by veracrypt. Of course I've tried also real live trial of copying bigger files by simple windows explorer copy with same results. I've found your question  by searching why it does perform so badly, and I see that's really uncommon, rare, but apparent bug that's affecting many people. And becouse of strange condition to happen it's not even reported to veracrypt other than I saw one or two badly described cases from around 2018,which is year of manufacture of 850pro as I remember, but described without many details - with one common thing of that 10 times lower writing speed when encrypted :)
Mayby I'll test more disk, since I've got many more of many manufacturers disks. And Mayby I'll report that bug, becouse I'm really interested why that happend.

Comment: Hello, "long answer" doesn't have to be "block of text" answer.

Comment: It has to, to make clear every efford I've taken to prove it's specific to that particlular ssd model..

Comment: At least pressing Enter several times definitely doesn't hurt...

Comment: Omg, sorry, you don't have to read it if it's too complicated...

Comment: Sure, I can downvote it though, if you fail and don't want to understand why readability of answers is important.